# Finding MEAN or AVERAGE using Excel

Tags: excel, math, statistics, mean, normal-distribution

I am not sure what's the best term to call this. Hope you guys can shed some lights. I am trying to find which number range occurs the most in a long list of numbers.

Is there any Excel formula that can help me ? I try to do average but if I have one big number, the average will be off. Thanks.

```
3.87
7.78
3.03
5.8
2.95
4.97
7.45
7.1
6.38
8.27
6.53
7.03
6.43
4.87
6.22
4.23
4.1
3.43
3.38
22.77
19.83
16.97
14.57
51.88
```

Comment: What error do you get when using average?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "number range"? If you mean an actual number, use `MODE()`, but that gives an error for your sample list since no number is repeated. You could also try `MODE.MULT()` or `MODE.SNGL()`.

Answer (score 0):

To find the average of the "best fit" you can use this array formula, exclude any outliers:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ABS(AVERAGE($A$1:$A$24)-$A$1:$A$24)/STDEV.P($A$1:$A$24)<3,$A$1:$A$24))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

You can change the `3` to by more precise or less depending on the cutoff for outliers.

What this does currently is exclude any numbers greater than 3 standard deviations from the mean.  So in the case of the data provide `51.88` will be excluded from the average.

[image]

---

Note:

I read:

```
I am trying to find which number range occurs the most in a long list of numbers.
```

not as finding the one number that occurs the most, but taking into context the rest, as excluding the outliers from the average formula.

Comment: The number looks like what I am after ... I will try your formula on a desktop later. Thanks.

Comment: Excluding outliers can be a dangerous thing to do.  Sometimes they're real data that are telling you something important.  What are you really trying to do?  What is the real problem here?

Comment: I plotted it using Histogram and it is much clearer. I'll let the user deal with the outliers whether to include or exclude in their consideration. Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

> if I have one big number, the average will be off

Incorrect.  The average calculation you get from Excel is correct.

This is how outliers work.

Median is less sensitive to outliers.  Try it if you're worried.

I'd recommend plotting the histogram of your data to get a sense for the distribution and skew.

Comment: Do you provide answers, or just comment and downvote others?  Looking at the data, every number in the list has a count of one.  Not useful, IMO.

Comment: I plotted scatter plot and I can see the number between 4 to 7 ranges. Not sure about Histogram in Excel but I will try it out.